# Is there a possibility to deactivate a button in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Is there a possibility to deactivate a button in SwiftUI? Can not find anything?

I want to do a download with Alamofire and then activate the button after successful download.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `.disabled` modifier. According to the documentation:

> Adds a condition that controls whether users can interact with this
>   view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var buttonDisabled = true

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            //your action here
        }) {
            Text("CLICK ME!")
        }
        .disabled(buttonDisabled)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
#endif
```

You can set your `buttonDisabled` State var to false when your download completes.

Comment: but disabled() also changes the appearance of the button label..

Comment: @JonathanK Then use the `allowsHitTesting` modifier. It doesn't modify the appearance of the view.